# Media query is not working correctly when I view my site on my phone

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a navigation menu for mobile and one for a normal computer screen. And when the window width decreases it gets rid of the desktop menu and shows the mobile menu instead. This works on chrome when I make the window smaller, but when I look at my site from my phone, the menu isn't showing. I have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in the `<head>` tag.

Code provided below.

```
<div class="mobilemenu">
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
    <a href="#">link 2</a>
</div>

<div class="desktopmenu">
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
    <a href="#">link 2</a>
</div>
```

And this is the css

```
.desktopmenu {
   display: block;
}

.mobilemenu {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px){
    .desktopmenu {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobilemenu {
        margin-top: -46px !important; /* this is because of the wordpress header */
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set `margin-top: -46px` and your menu in goes out of `body`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the css setting `margin-top:-46px`.
You probably had a css markup also for the `header` that made the header invisible, which that you have removed or forgot to add to `@media`.
You can either remove the line

```
margin-top: -46px !important; /* this is because of the wordpress header */
```

or add the `header` css markup to `@media` if you have copied this from somewhere.
I personally suggest the latter.